# Change location of the name of the object

Tags: python

When setting, in Python, "show_name = True" all my objects show their names as desired.

However since objects are close to each other the names get scrambled.
Hence I want to change the position of the name of the object.

Right now the name seems to be attached to the pivot-point.
Location Pivot point however may not be changed.

Any ideas?